# Site monitoring tool to look for javascript errors

Tags: javascript, monitoring

I am currently working on a site that includes javascript code that we get from several different sources and need to run on the site I maintain. Every once and a while some of this code breaks without our knowing until its too late. Is there a monitoring tool that will crawl our site and look for javascript errors and report them or could this be incorporated into a selenium test somehow?

Comment: If you are on ASP.NET this assembly can be used to report them back to the server http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2006/05/02/Logging-JavaScript-Errors-To-ASP.NET.aspx

Comment: Thanks Martin, that solution sounds ideal but I need to support classic asp in this case.

Comment: You cannot figure out all errors in the development stage. You can use tool like **atatus** to capture errors in the runtime. https://www.atatus.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the sites I develop, I wrap everything in `try ... catch` blocks, and if the exceptions I catch cannot be handled, I always generate an AJAX request to a script which emails an error report to the development team with as much information as I can gather.

If the code is code you didn't write yourself and `try...catch` blocks would be difficult to add, you can use the [window.onerror handler](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error2.shtml) instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onerror = function()
{
  // Your code to generate an AJAX request to your error report script here
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should be careful to build throttling logic into this or you can accidentally DDoS your error endpoint. If you want to get better error information and not worry about error volume, check out a hosted solution like [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com). Disclosure: I am one of the original founders.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but recently we've launched a tool that does this :)

It's called ConsoleWatch - https://www.consolewatch.io/

It lets you scan whole websites for JS errors and also schedule repeating scans with reports, so you might find t handy!

Answer (score -2):

It would also be smart to utilize a tool that will catch any JavaScript errors that might happen after production. There're several tools out there but I recommend RootCause because it will allow you to automatically reproduce any user errors.

Disclaimer: I work for [RootCause](https://therootcause.io/feature-tour/). Our software automatically reproduces JavaScript errors and lets you replay user sessions live in your browser with the click of a button.